# Meaning of java.sql.SQLException PWS0005 Error occurred in the database

Tags: java, sql, tomcat, servlets, genexus

Having random issues when launch web panels and getting either PSW005.  This error is random as the same operation can be performed without error.  IBM has been of little help even after sending logs.  Has anyone encountered this error?

We are running on Tomcat 9.0 using the IBM iSeries (AS/400) as a database server.  The system has been rewritten with Java to replace the traditional "Green-Screen" system.

21-Dec-2018 13:11:16.781 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-24] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [gpweb.wwelcome] in context with path [/gpweb] threw exception [java.lang.ClassCastException: com.genexus.db.driver.DataSourceConnectionPool cannot be cast to com.genexus.db.driver.ConnectionPool
    at com.genexus.db.driver.DataSource.disconnectOnException(DataSource.java:442)
    at com.genexus.db.ServerUserInformation.disconnectOnException(ServerUserInformation.java:83)
    at com.genexus.db.DBConnectionManager.disconnectOnException(DBConnectionManager.java:255)
    at com.genexus.Application.GXLocalException(Application.java:588)
    at com.genexus.Application.GXLocalException(Application.java:577)
    at com.genexus.Application.GXLocalException(Application.java:572)
    at com.genexus.Application.rollback(Application.java:930)
    at com.genexus.Application.rollback(Application.java:868)
    at com.genexus.db.DefaultExceptionErrorHandler.handleSQLError(DefaultExceptionErrorHandler.java:45)
    at com.genexus.db.DataStoreProvider.execute(DataStoreProvider.java:233)
    at com.genexus.db.DataStoreProvider.execute(DataStoreProvider.java:200)
    at com.genexus.db.DataStoreProvider.execute(DataStoreProvider.java:192)
    at gpweb.mambosettingstoplink.privateExecute(mambosettingstoplink.java:61)
    at gpweb.mambosettingstoplink.execute_int(mambosettingstoplink.java:54)
    at gpweb.mambosettingstoplink.execute(mambosettingstoplink.java:43)
    at gpweb.amambobuildnavbartoplinks.privateExecute(amambobuildnavbartoplinks.java:101)
    at gpweb.amambobuildnavbartoplinks.execute_int(amambobuildnavbartoplinks.java:90)
    at gpweb.amambobuildnavbartoplinks.execute(amambobuildnavbartoplinks.java:76)
    at gpweb.mambobuildnavbartoplinks.execute_int(mambobuildnavbartoplinks.java:79)
    at gpweb.mambobuildnavbartoplinks.execute(mambobuildnavbartoplinks.java:69)
    at gpweb.mambomasterpage_impl.e130B2(mambomasterpage_impl.java:645)
    at gpweb.mambomasterpage_impl.rf0B2(mambomasterpage_impl.java:524)
    at gpweb.mambomasterpage_impl.refresh(mambomasterpage_impl.java:502)
    at gpweb.mambomasterpage_impl.we0B2(mambomasterpage_impl.java:448)
    at gpweb.mambomasterpage_impl.webExecute(mambomasterpage_impl.java:59)
    at gpweb.wwelcome_impl.webExecute(wwelcome_impl.java:118)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebPanel.webExecuteEx(GXWebPanel.java:358)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebPanel.doExecute(GXWebPanel.java:373)
    at gpweb.wwelcome.doExecute(wwelcome.java:23)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callDoExecute(GXWebObjectStub.java:228)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callExecute(GXWebObjectStub.java:137)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.doGet(GXWebObjectStub.java:44)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.genexus.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:417)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
] with root cause
 javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.genexus.db.driver.DataSourceConnectionPool cannot be cast to com.genexus.db.driver.ConnectionPool
    at com.genexus.db.driver.DataSource.disconnectOnException(DataSource.java:442)
    at com.genexus.db.ServerUserInformation.disconnectOnException(ServerUserInformation.java:83)
    at com.genexus.db.DBConnectionManager.disconnectOnException(DBConnectionManager.java:255)
    at com.genexus.Application.GXLocalException(Application.java:588)
    at com.genexus.Application.GXLocalException(Application.java:577)
    at com.genexus.Application.GXLocalException(Application.java:572)
    at com.genexus.Application.rollback(Application.java:930)
    at com.genexus.Application.rollback(Application.java:868)
    at com.genexus.db.DefaultExceptionErrorHandler.handleSQLError(DefaultExceptionErrorHandler.java:45)
    at com.genexus.db.DataStoreProvider.execute(DataStoreProvider.java:233)
    at com.genexus.db.DataStoreProvider.execute(DataStoreProvider.java:200)
    at com.genexus.db.DataStoreProvider.execute(DataStoreProvider.java:192)
    at gpweb.mambosettingstoplink.privateExecute(mambosettingstoplink.java:61)
    at gpweb.mambosettingstoplink.execute_int(mambosettingstoplink.java:54)
    at gpweb.mambosettingstoplink.execute(mambosettingstoplink.java:43)
    at gpweb.amambobuildnavbartoplinks.privateExecute(amambobuildnavbartoplinks.java:101)
    at gpweb.amambobuildnavbartoplinks.execute_int(amambobuildnavbartoplinks.java:90)
    at gpweb.amambobuildnavbartoplinks.execute(amambobuildnavbartoplinks.java:76)
    at gpweb.mambobuildnavbartoplinks.execute_int(mambobuildnavbartoplinks.java:79)
    at gpweb.mambobuildnavbartoplinks.execute(mambobuildnavbartoplinks.java:69)
    at gpweb.mambomasterpage_impl.e130B2(mambomasterpage_impl.java:645)
    at gpweb.mambomasterpage_impl.rf0B2(mambomasterpage_impl.java:524)
    at gpweb.mambomasterpage_impl.refresh(mambomasterpage_impl.java:502)
    at gpweb.mambomasterpage_impl.we0B2(mambomasterpage_impl.java:448)
    at gpweb.mambomasterpage_impl.webExecute(mambomasterpage_impl.java:59)
    at gpweb.wwelcome_impl.webExecute(wwelcome_impl.java:118)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebPanel.webExecuteEx(GXWebPanel.java:358)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebPanel.doExecute(GXWebPanel.java:373)
    at gpweb.wwelcome.doExecute(wwelcome.java:23)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callDoExecute(GXWebObjectStub.java:228)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callExecute(GXWebObjectStub.java:137)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.doGet(GXWebObjectStub.java:44)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.genexus.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:417)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

```
at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callExecute(GXWebObjectStub.java:221)
at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.doGet(GXWebObjectStub.java:44)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.genexus.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:417)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Genexus! Really! I haven't heard of that uruguayan company since the mid 90s. Is it still alive?

Comment: There is no SQLException in your log. Question body and question title are not related.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a comment that does not fit in the comments section.

> com.genexus.db.driver.DataSourceConnectionPool cannot be cast to 
>   com.genexus.db.driver.ConnectionPool at

This looks a lot like a configuration issue. It seems that Genexus is trying to use its own database connection pool, but for some reason it cannot handle the internal class `com.genexus.db.driver.DataSourceConnectionPool`.

You should check:

- Is the Genexus Datbase Connection Pool of the right version?
- Is the JDBC driver correct for the Java version and Tomcat version you are trying to use?
- Are you deploying with the same Genexus, Tomcat, JDBC driver, and Database Connection Pool as you are developing?

Definitively there's something off in the infrastructure. If necessary, reinstall Tomcat from scratch paying attention to each one of the extra libraries you are adding to it, and each piece of extra configuration.

This is unlikely an error on Tomcat. More like an error in the setup of your server, or the WAR file you are deploying.

Comment: It turned out the iSeries needed a PTF patch applied.  It resolved our issue.